# Declare a pointer in a class but initialize in another thread

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, memory

I declare a pointer called download_webm in the main class and i want to initialize it in my thread constructor but every time I try to do that the program crash when I try to connect download WebM and player.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    int x;

    DownloadWebm *download_webm;

    MyThread *DownloadWebm_Thread = new  MyThread(download_webm);



    DownloadWebm_Thread->start();


    LinuWebmPlayer *player = new LinuWebmPlayer(argv[1],0);
    QObject::connect(download_webm,SIGNAL(send_packege(Video_Bytes_Package)),player,SLOT(play()));
    player->show();





    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is my thread header :

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H
#include <qthread.h>
#include <downloadwebm.h>
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyThread(DownloadWebm *);
    MyThread();

protected:
    DownloadWebm **webm;
    void run();
};





#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

, and CPP :

```
#include "mythread.h"

MyThread::MyThread()
{

}

MyThread::MyThread(DownloadWebm* we)
{
   webm = &we;
}

void MyThread::run()
{
   *webm = new DownloadWebm("http://trilulilu.de/recstreamingsource?movie=3860","asd");
}
```

The main class sees the download_webm pointer as uninitialized!

Comment: Why the double pointer?

Comment: because I want  webm  to point to the  download_webm pointer and initialize the download_webm in the run function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MyThread::MyThread(DownloadWebm* we)
```

`we` is a parameter to this function, namely the thread constructor. By default, function parameters get passed ***by value***. Wherever `we` came from, effectively this `we` is a copy of it. This is what this `we` is. A copy of the original value that gets passed into this function. Completely independent from the value specified in the function call that invokes this.

```
webm = &we;
```

A pointer to `we` gets saved. Immediately afterwards the constructor returns. `we` no longer exists. It gets destroyed. It is an ex-parameter. Once a function call returns, all parameters to the function call get destroyed. This saved pointer now points to a destroyed object that no longer exists (remember that `we` is a copy of whatever `we` actually came from).

Subsequent attempts to dereference this pointer results in an attempt to access a destroyed object. That's your undefined behavior, and crash.

In your `main()`:

```
MyThread *DownloadWebm_Thread = new  MyThread(download_webm);
```

`download_webm` is an uninitialized pointer, so passing a copy of it to the constructor is undefined behavior, as well. It is logically impossible for the constructor to access `download_webm` because its parameter is an independent copy of this uninitialized pointer.

You can pass a ***pointer*** to `download_webm`, instead:

```
MyThread *DownloadWebm_Thread = new  MyThread(&download_webm);
```

And the constructor's declaration and code gets adjusted accordingly.

You can also pass a reference to `download_webm`, which will be more C++-like, if you wish. In which case the parameter to the constructor must be declared as a reference to a pointer:

```
MyThread::MyThread(DownloadWebm *&we)
```

With the rest of the existing code mostly remaining unchanged, in this case.